# Generating a random code in c

Tags: c, barcode

I'm trying to generate a random 10-digit code, but even though I use the absolute value of every number in the code, it still sometimes prints a negative value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int r;
    int barcode[11];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i <= 10;i++){
        r = rand() % 10;
        barcode[i] = abs(r);
    }
    printf("%d",barcode);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Because you are actually printing the address of an integer array, not a string.

This line:

```
printf("%d",barcode);
```

Basically prints the address of `barcode` as a signed integer instead of the contents of barcode.

You of course could do this:

```
printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",barcode[0], barcode[1], barcode[2], barcode[3], barcode[4], barcode[5], barcode[6], barcode[7], barcode[8], barcode[9]);
```

But perhaps a better way is to generate a string of characters instead of an array of integers.  Quick mod to your code is to add to `'0'` to each random value in each interation of the loop and append to a char array.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int r;
    char barcode[11];          // array of chars instead of ints
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)      // loop 10 times, not 11
    {
        r = rand() % 10;
        barcode[i] = '0' + r;  // convert the value of r to a printable char
    }
    barcode[10] = '\0';        // null terminate your string
    printf("%s\n",barcode);
    return 0;
}
```

The above will generate a 10 digit code, with a small possibility of the first number being a leading zero. If that's not what you want, that's a simple bug fix. (Which I'll leave up to you...)

Comment: So why is it necessary to add the '0' to the random number when it's generated?

Comment: '0' is the lowest ASCII character for the ten numericals. You are essentially adding 48 to the integer returned by the first digit generated by the RNG.